# Exception while connecting hive and sparkThe root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I m using Spark 2.4.5,
Hive 3.1.2,
Hadoop 3.2.1.
While running hive in spark i got the following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rwxrwxr-x;
```

This is my source code,

```
package com.spark.hiveconnect

import java.io.File

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SaveMode, SparkSession}

object sourceToHIve {
  case class Record(key: Int, value: String)
  def main(args: Array[String]){
    val warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("Spark Hive Example").master("local")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._
    import spark.sql

    sql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS src (key INT, value STRING) USING hive")
    sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/usr/local/spark3/examples/src/main/resources/kv1.txt' INTO TABLE src")
    sql("SELECT * FROM src").show()

    spark.stop()
  }

}
```

This is my sbt file

```
name := "SparkHive"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.5"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "8.0.19"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.4.5"
```

How can solve this Issue?
While observing the console i also saw this statement, is this the reason why i am getting this issue.

```
20/05/28 14:03:04 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(UDHAV.MAHATA); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(UDHAV.MAHATA); groups with modify permissions: Set()
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change permissions from the shell

```
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive
```

or run your spark process with another user or application under the right permissions.

You change the owner of a directory or a file using:

```
-chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] PATH... :
  Changes owner and group of a file. This is similar to the shell's chown command
  with a few exceptions.

  -R  modifies the files recursively.
```

Comment: i already tried that its still not working. My source code and hadoop are running in different users. Source code in UDHAV.MAHATA, hadoop and hive are in hadoopuser. Is that the issue?

Comment: I think so, you have to change the permissions with the right user.

Comment: you can try ````sudo -su root````

Comment: and then ````hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive````

Comment: I tried running the above 2 commands but it still isnt working. can you write it in a new answer that how should solve this issue. I am running my souce code in intellij in a user while my hadoop and hive are runningin another user. Thank you.

Comment: Even after copying my project to the hadoop user using `cp` cmd it didnt work. I am not able run my code in the other hadoop user